# Python: Scripts folder is blank and no pip files

Tags: python, windows, pip, taurus

Installed python installed on system of version 3.8.5 but there is an error with pip. pip is not installed

Below is the path

```
C:\Users\Comp1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts
```

Found some results and tried running `python get-pip.py` from cmd but didn't work.
Also checked PATH and was correct

After using pip command in cmd it gives "pip is not recoganized"

Please let me know how can I fix this issue.

Comment: "Python38-32" is the default installation directory for 32-bit Python 3.8, but you say you installed 3.7. Check `where.exe python` to see which installation you're running.

Comment: The latest stable release is 3.8.5, which is probably the version you want. Also, install the 64-bit build, unless you really need 32-bit.

Comment: Uninstall the 32-bit version, and install the 3.8.5 [Windows x86-64 executable installer](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-385/) (scroll down to the files section). In the installer setup, make sure the options are selected to install pip and to add Python to the environment variables. After installing, open a new command prompt from Explorer.

Comment: yes followed the same step but still Scripts folder is empty

Comment: If you installed the 64-bit version, it wouldn't default to using "Python38-32". It would either be in "%LocalAppData%\Programs\Python\Python38" or "%ProgramFiles%\Python38".

Comment: You've apparently installed both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Python 3.8 both for the current user in `%LocalAppData%` and for all users in `%ProgramFiles%` and `%ProgramFiles(x86)%`. First pick the one you want to use and uninstall the others, delete their directories, and clean all entries referring to them from the system and user `PATH` environment variables. Once you have it paired down to just the installation you want, try repairing it, with the option to install pip selected. If repairing doesn't work, from the command prompt try `python -m ensurepip --upgrade --default-pip`.

Comment: same result. No Luck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220903/discussion-between-dhanesh-and-eryk-sun).